# Connect Heroku app to Atlas MongoDB using static IP

Tags: heroku, static-ip-address, quotaguard

I'm trying to connect my **Heroku app** to **Atlas MongoDB** using **static IP**.

I've installed QuotaGuard Shield Static IP.

When running `heroku run bash` and then running `curl http://icanhazip.com/` I get a different IP than then ones mentioned in QuotaGuard Shield's dashboard.

Does anyone know what am I missing in the configuration of **QG Shield**?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `curl -x $QUOTAGUARDSHIELD_URL http://icanhazip.com`.

You have to tell curl to use the proxy.